# Is there any performance difference between using " = " and " LIKE "?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

To start I would like to mention that I tried Googling this to no avail.

I would like the option of using wildcards in all my columns. Therefore I would like all my `SELECT` statements to use `LIKE` instead of `=`. Let me point out that there is **NO** user input data in my application, which rules out any concern of injection attacks.

Is there any speed difference between the two if the rest of the query remains identical? (That is, if the right-hand side of the condition contains no wildcards.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference.

WHERE firstname LIKE 'Fred'

is not perceptibly different from

WHERE firstname = 'Fred'

So you're free to use "LIKE" rather than "=" in all your cases where you
want the presence of a wildcard character to control whether or not to
invoke the wildcard search.

I can't find the reference  but I've seen this mentioned more than once, and it
makes sense. The index strategy will be equivalent either way (it can only match
the same characters on the same indexes) and I have sometimes written queries this
way because presence or absence of a wildcard in a particular invocation is acceptable.
Also, I've never seen a case where someone tried to parse out the presence of a wild
character and invoke the SQl differently based on the circumstances. It would perhaps
be risky to do so because it would be easier to write an inefficient (unSARGable) query with an expression in the wrong place.

Comment: s/is not/is not based on actual testing/

Comment: reference: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning

Comment: Interesting example - SELECT first_name, last_name, date_of_birth
  FROM employees
 WHERE UPPER(last_name) LIKE 'WIN%D' - The biggest problem is it's not optimizable because of the UPPER operation on the column value - it would do just as badly with UPPER(last_name) = 'WINWOOD'.

Comment: The example is from the middle of the book. In that case, the UPPER is tuned by an function-based-index ... but they don't exist in MySQL. However, the LIKE explanation is valid for all databases...and I have definitely to think to change the example to work without UPPER.

Answer (score 2):

Any decent DBMS should detect a non-wildcard string in the `like` and treat it exactly the same as an `=`. But even this check will take some time, however minuscule.

As stated, the time taken for this would be minimal and would only happen once per query. The sort of performance problems you *really* need to watch out for are things that incur a cost per row, such as `select to_lower(column_name)`. In other words, you probably needn't concern yourself with your particular case.

If you *had* used wildcards, then it would almost certainly be slower, simply because you'd have to check partial columns. A clause like `like 'xyz%'` wouldn't be too much slower but wildcards anywhere other than at the end of the string would cause more serious problems.

But, if you *were* using wildcards, you wouldn't have an option - `like` would be the only possibility.

Bottom line: unless your DBMS is brain-dead, the difference between `=` and `like` for non-wildcard strings will be insignificant.

But, as with all database optimisations: *measure, don't guess!*

---

I *do* remain confused by one aspect of your question though. You state:

> Let me point out that there is NO user input data in my application.

which I assume is to ensure us that SQL injection attacks are not possible.

But because of that, surely you know in advance (in the code) whether the query will be a wildcard or non-wildcard one. In which case, why wouldn't you just use the `=` variant where appropriate and remove all doubt.

And if, as you state in comments, there are *no* wildcard queries, why would you even *consider* using `like`.

Comment: I have one function that performs a `SELECT` query. Sure I could add some code to check if the input string contains a wildcard symbol, but why would I do that if `=` and `LIKE` are identical in all other cases anyway? That's pretty much why I posted this question. It can also be handy to know this in advance in the future.

Comment: @Codemonkey, it becomes clearer now. The difference _should_ be minuscule but, if you're worried about even that, provide two functions, one with `=` and one with `like` then make sure you (or anyone else) calls the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although how much depends.

If the column is indexed, then it can be quite a bit slower. Especially if you compare to something like `'%suffix'` because the index can't be used at all when the percent sign appears at the start of the search string.

Comment: My question specifies "if the rest of the query remains identical". Could you edit?

Answer (score 0):

What @Jonathan Wood said. When you ask MySQL, for example, to find values using the wildcard '%' the server has to read every single row in the entire table looking for matches.

Comment: Didn't anyone read the question? I implicitly specified "if the rest of the query remains identical". No wildcards.

Comment: @Codemonkey, we read the question. You stated explicitly "I would like the option of using wildcards". This seems to fly in the face of your "No wildcards" comment above. Which is it?

Comment: OK, let me clarify: 99.99% of the `SELECT` queries will be without wildcards. It is the performance of those 99.99% of my queries I am worried about. I am wondering if the performance impact of exclusively using `LIKE` instead of `=` justifies adding code to distinct between input containing and not containing any wildcards.

Comment: MySQL only needs to read every row if you put the '%' in front of the other characters. It will use an index just fine if you query for "first_name LIKE 'Alexande%'.

Comment: @Codemonkey, when I see the statement "I would like the option of using wildcards in all my columns" somehow the idea of "no wildcards" doesn't quite come through.

Comment: @Pete Wilson: That's my bad. When I said all my columns, I didn't mean all my rows. I just want the option of using wildcards in any/all of my columns :-)

Comment: @Codemonkey -- if you're going to clarify your question, how about editing the question itself rather than burying the clarification in some comment. It's an interesting question so please let everybody see the real thing. Thanks.